# Is Forefront v10 compatible with SharePoint Foundation 2010

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, wss-3.0, forefront

We're using WSS 3.0 with ForeFront v10, and looking to upgrade SharePoint to Foundation 2010. From looking at the Wikipedia page http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Forefront it seems to imply that we would need to install a newer version of ForeFront in order to get it to work with SP 2010.

Can anyone confirm this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that v10 is not compatible. After upgrading SP to 2010, Forefront v10 caused problems and the SharePoint Central Admin website was not accessible. So we installed Forefront Protection for SharePoint 2010, and everything started working again.